# An Anime Affix Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle, anime

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

My prefix hosted* talk to beat a killer from within.
My infix works for former bandit, shooting with their twin.
My suffix can be found in range of anime-like weapon.
My whole, while very powerless, caught peaceful man's attention.

Hint:

> The anime referenced on the second line is significantly more obscure than the others; the twin shares a name with a virtual shark.

Hint 2:

> As promised in a *comment* below: The anime from the first line and the third line have a similar spirit.

---

*<sup>Originally "...prefix lead a talk..."; my bad!</sup>

Comment: If I may ask, why the downvotes?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think some people downvote affix riddles out of principle

Comment: @LukasRotter How nice of them! Now that we have a tag for these riddles, they should be very easy to avoid for those who don't like them. - And of cause easier to find for those with a grudge.

Comment: @LukasRotter Why would there be such a principle?

Comment: @riskymysteries I'd say they're sick of them (since there have been so many in the past) and regard them as low-effort (+low quality) puzzles

Comment: @LukasRotter Hmm... I actually wish there were more for me to solve. Also, judging by the views they receive, a lot of people *(not necessarily with accounts)* enjoy them.

Comment: @LukasRotter I actually don't enjoy logical deduction puzzles, yet there are so many. I simply ignore them, but do you think it would be a good reason for me to downvote them as a "principle"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Midoriya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_My_Hero_Academia_characters#Izuku_Midoriya), from My Hero Academia

My prefix led a talk to beat a killer from within.

> [Mido](https://getbackers.fandom.com/wiki/Ban_Mido) who is said to use the *Evil Eye* to enter into the mind of his opponent, and see their entire past. He has made someone believed that they were dead, up until the point where the belief became reality.

My infix works for former bandit, shooting with their twin.

> This is [Dori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Utawarerumono_characters#Dor%C4%AB_&_Gur%C4%81) from Utawarerumono, who shoots arrows with their twin Gura and works for the former bandit Oboro.

My suffix can be found in range of anime-like weapon.

> I think this may be **Oriya** from [Descendants of Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Descendants_of_Darkness_characters) who is an expert with a katana (which could be described as an anime-like weapon and of which an expert might find themselves in range).

My whole, while very powerless, caught peaceful man's attention.

> Midoriya Izuku is the main protagonist of the series who, despite being *quirkless*, is chosen by All Might (referred to by many as the Symbol for Peace) to become the ninth holder of One For All.

Comment: You've got the infix and the whole! In all fairness, I realize the prefix line isn't quite right (I'll fix that). I'll leave this up for a bit in case someone can get the other two affixes, but if not, there's a check coming your way!

Comment: Ah, I had thought the suffix might be wrong alright but thought I was good on the prefix (will have to rethink this)

Comment: This suffix isn't was I was thinking, but I much prefer it to mine. I was thinking of rot13(gur Wncnarfr jbeq "[ln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya_(arrow))" juvpu zrnaf "neebj". Guvf bar jnf n yvggyr ebhture, ohg n "enatrq jrncba" = obj, sbhaq jvgu neebjf, genafyngrq gb Wncnarfr. V ernyyl cersre lbhef gubhtu, fvapr vg sbyybjf gur cnggrea bs gur bgure yvarf - V gevrq gb svaq na navzr punenpgre gung jbhyq jbex nf n fhssvk, ohg V pbhyqa'g sbe jungrire ernfba.) I almost want to accept, but I think there's a better fit for the prefix - hint incoming!

Comment: I completely forgot about this, and I'm really not sure how to hint it better. My intention for the prefix was rot13([Zvqb](http://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Shingo_Mido), sebz Qrngu Abgr, jub ubfgrq n gnyx ng uvf ubhfr gb gel naq qrqhpr gur vqragvgl bs Xven, gur xvyyre, sebz nzbat gurve enaxf). The second hint was supposed to mean: rot13(n flabalz sbe "pbzzrag" vf "abgr", naq Qrfpraqnagf bs Qnexarff naq Qrngu Abgr obgu srngher Fuvavtnzv. V qvqa'g znxr vg pyrne va gur uvag vs gur guveq yvar ersreerq gb zl bevtvany fbyhgvba be lbhe orggre bar, fb gung'f ba zr).